# How do I club two string formats, or add a character to a string format

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-formatting

I have been trying to display a double with a '%' sign.
I cant use `"P2"` string format due to the fact that we want user to enter percentage that is saved as it is.

Hence we did use `.DataFormatString = "{0}%"` to display a '%' sign at the end of our data.
but this displays data like 1.2300000000%.

Now to  truncate trailing zeros we were tempted to use `.DataFormatString = "G29"` which would effectively remove all unnecessary zeros but now how do we add a `"%"` sign at the end of string ?

Can we somehow club two string formats to use `"G29"` with `"%"` sign ?

I have made various attempts to format this, but none have been on target, might be very simple one that I am missing..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the right track:

```
string result = string.Format("{0:G29}%", 1.2300000000);
```

Comment: Spot ON ! , cant believe I missed that